# Unix how to use 'command()' in bash

Tags: bash, unix

maybe this is a total noob question. But I do not know how to use this.
For example when I have 'stat' I can use 'stat /home/'. But when I type stat() a new Line starting with '>  ' comes up. Can anyone tell me what to do with that? I am just curious because there is lstat (man lstat) but I cannot use it - System won't find it. But there is lstat().

Maybe you can help me to resolve this or to ask the question some better. (Reformatting welcomed as well I know I suck in those things)

Edit: I noticed you can type anything before brackets and it will start with the new line I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse a system call with an executable wrapper around that call. For instance, see `man 2 stat` for documentation about the system call named `stat`, and `man 1 stat` (or simply `man stat`) for documentation about the command `stat` that uses the system call to provide information about the requested files.

The shell does not provide direct access to system calls; its purpose is to run other programs.

When you type `stat()` at a shell prompt, you begin a shell function definition. The `>` indicates that the shell is waiting for the rest of the definition. For example:

```
$ foo()
> { echo hello; }
$ foo
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, the syntax `stat()` starts the definition of a function called `stat`. You don't call functions that way in a shell, just use the same syntax as for commands defined on the path.

`lstat` is listed in the man page as `lstat(2)`, meaning the man page is in section 2 of man pages. That section is for OS calls from a program, not for shell commands. Try checking out the SYNOPSIS part of a man page to see how to use things: If there is a `#include` line, you can be pretty sure it's for C programmers.